# Ubuntu boots to grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have two systems installed previously Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I was trying to reinstall Ubuntu and format the Ubuntu OS partition using a tool in Windows 7.

When I have Ubuntu ready on a USB stick and restart my laptop, it prompts me with the GRUB rescue screen. If I boot from USB to install Ubuntu, it just hangs.

Anyway, I messed up everything. So my question is how can I boot Windows 7 now?

Comment: Another GRUB2 Rescue operation that you can do http://askubuntu.com/questions/229552/grub-rescue-after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb/720942#720942

Comment: Sorry typed twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a [Windows 7 Repair disc](http://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/), just insert that, make sure your BIOS is configured to boot from the DVD/CD drive first, and then boot into your Windows Repair Console to get things fixed up.

This [tutorial](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html) gives you an overview of how to use the repair tools on your Windows 7 Repair disc to fix the MBR so you can boot Windows 7 again.

Essentially, you're going to boot it into a command prompt on Windows 7 and then run the following commands:

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr
```

Or, try the automatic "Start-up Repair" option to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved. I followed this tutorial. http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-linux-boot-loader-from-startup-after-deleting-linux-partition-on-a-dual-boot-system/

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted! I was just a little late with my answer. :)