# About grub rescue command line

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

Please help me..

I have two hard disk in my laptop..window 7 and ubuntu..
I have problem to back in option menu..because i enter one of the list of ubuntu..
In option menu,,have a list which operatg system i can choose between ubuntu n window7 but the list stil have another menu for ubuntu..i make mistake to choose the another list of ubuntu..and now i have to fix the command line that have grub rescue..

like this :

```
        error : no such partition
        grub rescue >
```

i dont have any idea to fix this problem..i try the another step that i see at the other question but still dont have any answer..this problem is just i enter the another list but do not have any kernel,problem or somethg like that..

Comment: Do you mean to say that on the boot menu, when you selected Ubuntu, it gives you another list of options? They might just be kernel versions, have you tried rebooting and selecting another option (kernel) from the Ubuntu grub menu? Try reading these posts [error: no such partition grub rescue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145930/error-no-such-partition-grub-rescue) and [Ubuntu boot grub rescue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95253/ubuntu-boot-grub-rescue).

Answer (score 1):

You can type the command at grub rescue:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will install grub automatically to first hard disk boot. If you want to install grub on another hard disk just change "sda" to the approiate partition.

For example:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

This depends on you on which hard disk MBR you want to have grub. its much better to have grub on both the hard disks no matter whichever boots.

Quit the grub rescue mode and reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Using another PC, download "[Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk.iso/download)," burn the ISO image to a CD and boot from it. It should work. (It did for me.)