# How can I move grub ("multiboot") from usb to hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows, usb, xubuntu

I am new to linux. I installed xubuntu using a usb live disk. It installed correctly however grub (the multi os loader) is on the usb.  When I boot without the usb it only loads windows.  The installation is good since I can boot from the usb, once booted I can remove the stick and verify that the installation is on the hard drive.
How do i move safely move the boot mechanism from the usb to the hard drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue problem after installing ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229552/grub-rescue-problem-after-installing-ubuntu). That's about restoring GRUB when it's installed to the wrong device's MBR, which seems to be what's asked here. Another related question is [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). (That's a the more general question, not limited to situations where Windows triggered the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer to my own question in case someone needs this in the future.
The trick is to use boot-repair and make sure to select advance then install the mbr on the main hard drive (eg sba1).  Follow this url for more info - http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 0):

Boot with your usb attached, and type at a root terminal:

## grub-setup /dev/sda

Remove your usb and reboot.