# grub rescue when trying to fix dualboot with Windows 8, what can I do?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I formatted the partition containing Ubuntu 13.04 running parallel with Windows 8, I then merged the partition disk into another disk and that is where the problem starts.

When I restart the computer and I get **grub rescue**.

I searched for solution on net they advised me to repair by booting with Windows CD, this resulted in another problem and now it's saying "operating system wasn't found " and I can not boot with Windows CD.

My OS is windows 8.

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: See [Grub rescue problem after installing ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/229552/22949) and [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/22949). They should help in getting both the Windows and Ubuntu systems working, even though the cause of this problem is a bit different from the causes there (i.e., this is not the result of *installing* Windows or Ubuntu). If those don't help in getting rid of the GRUB rescue prompt, please edit your post with more info. For help with the Windows CD, I recommend [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 2):

#### Steps To Fix Windows 8 Boot

1. Boot from Windows CD/DVD and choose “Repair” when it shows up.
2. Choose Command Prompt on the resulting screen and run the following two commands:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmbr
   bootrec /fixboot
   ```
3. You are done!