# Using Ubuntu on external HD

Tags: dual-boot

I Have bought a 1TB USB external HD for my HP desktop (64 bit - 4GB RAM) to back up my windows 10 drive. Can I partition the external to hold ubuntu (dual boot) as well as the win backup? Is this advisable or will ubuntu run too slow?

Comment: Most of system once loaded is in RAM so just as fast. If USB3 will be just fine, even usb2 works but is slower. Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? But may be better to use gpt either way. With BIOS you need a bios_grub partition or with UEFI the ESP - efi system partition on external. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I was about to answer but the comment above is enough. Well done (again), sir.

Comment: Just be careful to place the Ubuntu bootloader, GRUB, on your external HDD. If you place it on the internal (Win 10) disk, you won't be able to boot your computer, because the bootloader will look for the files on the external HDD, assuming Ubuntu itself is installed there. Further explanations: http://askubuntu.com/questions/229552/grub-rescue-after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem though, if the external HDD will be plugged in all the time.